# How to differentiate case of a letter?

Tags: javascript, case-sensitive

```
function Convert_ONE2TWO()
{
    var arrTWO = new Array( "a", "e", "i");
    var arrONE = new Array( "A", "E", "I");
    str=document.frmConvert.txtONE.value; //input from ONE
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) //Loop for all letters
        {
        strTemp=new RegExp(arrONE[i], "ig");
        str=str.replace(strTemp,arrTWO[i]); //Replacing
        }
    document.frmConvert.txtTWO.value=str.toString(); //output to TWO
}

<form name="frmConvert" action="" method="get">
<textarea rows="5" cols="90" name="txtONE"></textarea>
<input name="btnConvertg" value="Create TWO" onclick="Convert_ONE2TWO();" type="Button">
<textarea rows="5" cols="90" name="txtTWO"></textarea>
</form>
```

I'm using this code. But, now got a problem. If the given text contains both upper case and lower case letters and if I want to change them to different values, for example:

```
    var arrTWO = new Array( "11", "12", "21", "22", "31", "33");
    var arrONE = new Array( "1A", "1a", "2E", "2e", "3I", "3i");
```

It's giving same value for both cases. Please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex uses the flags `ig` - the `i` there is for "Ignore case".

Just remove the `i` and it will become case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Your regexp is case-insensitive.  Try this:

```
    strTemp=new RegExp(arrONE[i], "g");
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `"i"` flag from your regex object. See http://jsfiddle.net/x6AbG/ for a working example. Your code should read:

```
function Convert_ONE2TWO()
{
  var arrTWO = new Array( "a", "e", "i");
  var arrONE = new Array( "A", "E", "I");
  str=document.frmConvert.txtONE.value; //input from ONE
  for (i=0;i<3;i++) //Loop for all letters
    {
    strTemp=new RegExp(arrONE[i], "g");
    str=str.replace(strTemp,arrTWO[i]); //Replacing
    }
  document.frmConvert.txtTWO.value=str.toString(); //output to TWO
}
```